# How to configure own shortcuts for styles?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> a selected text, it will become **bold**. Alas, this style is directly formatted, which means it gets lost once I default via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>. Yet whenever I reset the whole document, I only want it to lose some other direct styles, that I introduced by copying from different resources.

So I defined my own non-direct character style, "mybold", and am now wondering how to configure a keyboard shortcut to apply it onto the current marked text. As manually selecting it from the Styles and Formatting List gets very tiresome fast.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can assign keyboard shortcuts to styles in the Tools > Customize menu. In the "Keyboard" tab, the bottom of the Category field, you can expand Styles to find your custom styles. Then just assign them a shortcut in the top field, click Modify and OK.

Comment: It is and it did, so an upvote for you :-) For completeness sake it's "Tools" menu > "Customize...", then the "Keyboard" tab, then scroll down the "Category" field to the bottom etc. Also some non-custom styles already have shortcuts assigned, e.g. ctrl+shift+0 for default style, ctrl+1 for heading 1, ctrl+2 for heading 2 etc. See https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Shortcut_Keys_for_Writer#Shortcut_Keys_for_LibreOffice_Writer

Comment: ha. and Ctrl+[1,2,3] was already mapped to heading [1,2,3..] exactly as i was going to set to... but didn't bother to test before :)

Comment: Only problem with this is that it doesn't allow toggling of a style. With Ctrl-B for bold you can bold as you type and then end the bolding section by going Ctrl-B again. I presume that a macro would be needed for this in LO Writer. But then presumably you couldn't use the same hotkey for applying "mybold" (or whatever) to a selection of pre-existing text and also toggling on and off as you type... hmmm

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a **very old** question and that I should comment, but I don't have enough reputation. There's a very simple workaround to avoid the toggle problem. Just assign another shortcut (I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) to the default character style.